# Can I use the Youtube API to add captions to videos with Community contributions ON?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was wondering if the Youtube API supports uploading captions for videos that are not owned by the user but have Community contributions turned ON.

I have tried with a "OAuth 2.0 Client ID" credential but get the following error:
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/captions?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&part=snippet returned "The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to upload the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized.">

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use the required [authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/insert#auth) like https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner?

Comment: Yes, Used both of those. To add a bit more info on this, I'm able to upload captions using the API for videos that I own, but I want to do this for videos that I do not own that have community contributions turned on.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can only manipulate the captions via the API for videos that you own, or manage.  You cannot even read existing captions, like the auto-captions for videos that you do not own or manage.